# MoveMouseAction is not working in Microsoft WebDriver (for Edge browser)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

MoveToElement action method is not working when trying to run the tests with Edge browser using Microsoft Webdriver.

**Code snippet:**

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText("menu"))).perform();
```

**Observed below exception:**

> org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Unknown command received
>   Command duration or timeout: 10 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: 'unknown', time: '2015-07-30 11:02:44'
>   System info: host: 'DESKTOP-R1AE8BA', ip: '10.40.14.9', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
>   Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=true, browserVersion=20.10240.16384.0, platformVersion=10, browserName=MicrosoftEdge, takesScreenshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, takesElementScreenshot=true, platformName=windows, platform=ANY}]
>   Session ID: BC49145A-C839-49D7-890C-D06A13E904D8
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteExecuteMethod.execute(RemoteExecuteMethod.java:35)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteMouse.mouseMove(RemoteMouse.java:89)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveMouseAction.perform(MoveMouseAction.java:39)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.CompositeAction.perform(CompositeAction.java:50)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.perform(Actions.java:371)

As per Microsoft blogs, all the functions are not yet implemented, [List of commands implemented in Edge](http://dev.modern.ie/testdrive/demos/webdriver/), [Full list of commands](http://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/webdriver/details/)

Is there any alternative way to perform mouse over operations?

Comment: Unfortunately, you've already found the answer. If it's not supported by the driver, there's no way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

moveTo is not implemented yet, along with other methods such as "submit"

More details on the WebDriver implementation status can be found here: https://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/webdriver/details/